# Getting MAM Enabled: No , when i upload the apk to company portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have integrated Intune SDK into my application. When i upload the apk to Azure company portal. Getting error as MAM Enabled:No
So kindly advise how to resolve it

Earlier I had uploaded the app into the company portal with package name as com.anandtest.intune. Although i didnt receive any MAM enabled "No" ERROR.

{
"client_id" : "62cde6e7-bazf-48ar-950e-57ct9ccbbae4",
"authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
"redirect_uri" : "msauth:// com.anandtest.intune/Bi6pAfyxv71aWf%2BFrIiftyQ6yM4%3D",
"authorities" : [
{
"type": "AAD",
"audience": {
"type": "AzureADMyOrg",
"tenant_id": "63de7d59-2yte-42cw-a8cd-br7u4cff5eb6"
}
}
]
}

But when I upload the app with com.anand.intune package, getting the MAM enabled:NO error

{
"client_id" : "76cde78f-91z5-64ar-201e-57ct9rrttfw7",
"authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
"redirect_uri" : "msauth:// com.anand.intune/Bi6pAfyxv71aWf%2BFrIiftyQ6yM4%3D",
"authorities" : [
{
"type": "AAD",
"audience": {
"type": "AzureADMyOrg",
"tenant_id": "63de7d59-2yte-42cw-a8cd-br7u4cff5eb6"
}
}
]
}

Here although the tenant id is same in both packages but the client id is different

Comment: Hey @Anand, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

> Getting error as MAM Enabled:

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-get-started#configure-telemetry-for-your-app)

*It seems you have MAM enabled* ,

> If you choose not to send SDK telemetry data to Microsoft Intune from
> your app, you must disable telemetry transmission by setting the
> property `MAMTelemetryDisabled` to `"YES"` in the `IntuneMAMSettings`
> dictionary

---

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION|Troubleshooting app protection policy user issues***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/troubleshoot-mam).

Comment: The MAM enabled =NO is coming up when we try to upload the app under Android LOB app

Comment: Could you please refer this [Blog post](http://everythingaboutintune.com/2021/07/integrating-intune-sdk-in-any-lob-app-using-appdome/) to configure the MAM